# What is the fixed-on interval with regards to stepper motors?

Tags: pwm, driver, stepper-motor

I am using a stepper drive board to control a stepper motor. It has settings for for **fixed-on time** when using the open-loop PWM control method.

According to the API description:

```
The fixed-on time is the amount of time that the winding will be left
turned on at the beginning of the step, in order to let the current
rise as fast as possible. At the end of the fixed-on time, the control
signal switches to PWM.
```

Can someone please expand on this explanation as to why it is required?

I have set current limits for the motor, does this mean that it waits for the fixed-on time to let the current reach this level or is it something else. What would happen if I raise or lower this value, and how do I get the optimal value for this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed-on time is the time during which no current regulation is done (other than absolute current limiting). This allows for faster acceleration at the beginning of each pulse, if the motor is not in inertial motion already.

Fixed-on time ends early if current reaches desired value before time-out, and this is the ideal case for a running motor.

A balance must be struck between how quickly the motor spins up from a standstill, and how gently the acceleration pulses impact the mass while the motor is in inertial motion.

For large / high horsepower motors, standard lookup tables are often available. For small and hobby motors, it is pretty much an experimental science.

One way of looking at FoT is as a simplified PID mechanism.

Comment: Okay, so from what I gather, I can set the FoT to a higher than required time, but the driver will limit the current at the desired value before time-out. What would happen if FoT was too low - would the motor not reach its desired value?

Comment: It would still reach desired value, but more slowly. Less harsh on the mechanical parts, less vibration noise, better for domestic environments, but longer to get to where you want it to be. Of course, extremely low = step pulse is over before step is completed, motor just buzzes and goes nowhere.

Comment: Good explanation, but : More to the point than acceleration: the motor winding has inductance as well as resistance. Current through the winding (and therefore torque) increases slowly because of that inductance. The FOT maximises the drive voltage at the start of the pulse to reduce this delay.

Comment: So the FoT is only applied to each pulse during acceleration, and not during constant motion, am I right?

Comment: It's *applied* at every pulse, but has relevance only at accelerate / decelerate, is my belief, but I wouldn't guarantee that.

Comment: Because of FOT's role in opposing inductance, my understanding is that it is also relevant at constant speed.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is in large part to have enough space to discuss the points made in the currently-checked answer. (I've seen many good answers from Anindo, but this one is wide of the mark, I think!)

Background: To make a stepper motor advance from one position to the next, the controller changes the voltages across the stepper's coils to a new arrangement. This precipitates a change in current through the coils, but the current change is slowed by the coil's inductance. And reduced current means less magnetic force, and thus less torque.

To overcome the inductance problem, it's possible to apply higher voltages. But those higher voltages, if continued after the inductance effect,  would result in too much current, overheating etc.

To solve both problems, modern controllers use a high voltage, but "chop" it many times per second, so that for just holding the motor in a position, the coils see full voltage for only a fraction of the total time, but when advancing to the next step, the controller allows the full  voltage to be applied for a relatively long period, to build up the current against the action of the inductance.

A typical controller monitors the current and adjusts the chopping (or pulse) width accordingly for best effect ("Pulse Width Modulation" or PWM). But that's apparently difficult to do with precision during the advance-to-next-step period. So instead, during that period, controllers just issue a pulse of fixed time length.

That is the "Fixed on time" (also known as "blanking time", as the normal current-sample-to-pulse-width feedback is "blanked out".)

Data sheets for common stepper controller chips discuss the issues, Here's one for DRV8825, and updated version of the A4988 and similar.
pololu.com/file/download/drv8825.pdf?file_id=0J590

Now, to Anindo's post:

> The fixed-on time is the time during which no current regulation is done 
>   Correct: the time starting at the switch to a new phase. The controller applies full voltage to the selected winding(s), and the current is limited only by the winding inductance (and resistance).
>
> (other than absolute current limiting).

I believe in most popular controller ICs, the only current limiting is the PWM, which of course is disabled during FOT. There may be an overcurrent feature that shuts down the chip completely, but that doesn't contribute to normal operation of the controller.

> This allows for faster acceleration at the beginning of each pulse, if the motor is not in inertial motion already.

The FOT allows for faster buildup of current in a winding, up to the level intended for the torque required. It's about maintaining torque during a step, not about acceleration per se. It is as important during steady motion as during acceleration. Obviously, if the application features almost no static load, but a high-mass object (such as moving a heavy table horizontally on a 3D printer with good horizontal bearings) then the primary use for torque is to accelerate the load; moving it at a steady speed requires less torque. But if the motor is lifting, like in a simple winch, or moving something against drag (pushing filament in a 3D extruder) then considerable torque is called upon at steady speed.

> Fixed on-time ends early if current reaches desired value before time-out,

The point of the name "fixed" is that it doesn't end early. Perhaps there is a controller in which this term is misused, but in the chips I looked at, it's fixed.

> A balance must be struck between how quickly the motor spins up from a standstill, and how gently the acceleration pulses impact the mass while the motor is in inertial motion.

There are tradeoffs to be struck. But the more important one is the limit that coil inductance places on achieving a particular current quickly at the start of each phase, leading to a limit on the torque which can be achieved at any particular steps/sec. At a high steps/sec, a single phase may be so short in time that the current only builds to a fraction of what it would be when slower, and that reduced torque may be insufficient to overcome friction or other load, including any acceleration that is commanded.

The FOT doesn't solve this by itself. It is merely one of the features embodied in PWM stepper controllers, which allow using higher voltages to achieve designed currents earlier in a new phase (step), and consequently maintain torque at higher speeds.

It is true that faster buildup of current at the onset of each step will generally impart more vibration to the load. So there may be a tradeoff between vibration and max usable velocity or acceleration.

> For large / high horsepower motors, standard lookup tables are often available.

That's interesting.

> For small and hobby motors, it is pretty much an experimental science.

Although vendors (such as Pololu) do provide specs that include relevant parameters and graphs that are quite informative.

> One way of looking at FoT is as a simplified PID mechanism.

Actually, PID could apply to the current-sense-PWM feedback loop, but it's hard to see how it applies to the FOT which is a constant set at design time, and doesn't respond to any sensing or feedback. (Unless you think the designers have "integrated" their experience into the constant :-) )

OK, hope that helps.

Comment: Whoever left -1, care to say why?